# Limitar textos colocando reticências ao final, uso do angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tenho um texto que descreve um certo produto, essa descrição servirá como uma prévia, as reticências marcam que o texto continua, estou usando angular

```html
<p ng-bind-html="service.description | limitTo:150 "></p>
```

Este trecho do código limita perfeitamente o texto, gostaria de saber como insiro as reticências ao final do mesmo. 
Grato pela atenção!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode limitar a exibição com CSS, usando a propriedade [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

```css
p {
  max-width: 190px; /* Tamanho */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis.</p>
```

Dessa forma você não perde a informação, somente a limita visualmente. Se for preciso exibi-la por completo, não é preciso nenhuma programação com script ou mesmo realizar uma nova requisição para pegar o texto inteiro. Basta criar algo como o *snippet* abaixo, que mostra o conteúdo completo quando o cursor do mouse está sobre o parágrafo:

```css
p {
  max-width: 300px; /* Tamanho */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '... (continuar lendo)';
  white-space: nowrap
}

p:hover {
  text-overflow: clip;
  max-width: none
}
```

```html
<p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis.</p>
```

Comment: Boa ideia, o limitar já estava funcionando, o que está me perturbando é como limitar e adicionar, ao final do texto, as reticências.

Comment: Eu acho você deveria aceitar a outra resposta (se funcionar), visto que faz uso do Angular.

Answer (score 4):

No primeiro `{{}}` você exibe o seu `service.description` com a limitação de 150 caracteres, a seguir você faz uma verificação, se a quantidade (length) de caracteres for maior ou igual a 150, exibe as reticências, senão não.

```
<p>{{service.description | limitTo:150}}{{service.description.length >= 150 ? '...' : ''}}</p>
```

Comment: William, poderia adiciona mais detalhes a resposta.

Comment: Editei a resposta @DenerCarvalho

Comment: grato e marcado!

Comment: Não entendi por que desmarcaram minha resposta, há algo que não tenha ficado claro ainda?